# How evaluate this limit

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{h\to2} \frac{h^3 - 8}{h - 2} $$ Where $h$ is approaching $2$

So how do I work it out. I tried $\dfrac{(h-2)^3}{h-2}$ But that would cancels out.

Comment: **Careful!!!** $(h-2)^3\neq h^3-8$. For example, when $h=1$, the left side is $-1$ and the right side is $-7$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $h^3-8 = h^3-2^3 = (h-2)(h^2+2h+4)$
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 2} \frac{h^3 - 8}{h - 2} $$
$$=\lim_{h\rightarrow 2} \frac{(h-2)(h^2+2h+4)}{(h - 2)} $$
$$=2^2+2*2+4=12$$

**Note:** You can also use L'Hospital rule as mentioned by the other user.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer

Comment: @Orbit If you are satisfied with any answer, accept it so that others do not waste their time in posting another answer.

Answer (score 1):

lsp wrote the best, most elegant answer in his answer. Another way to calculate the limit is L'Hospital's rules, which gives you:
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 2}\frac{h^3-8}{h-2}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 2}\frac{3h^2}{1} = 3\cdot 2^2 = 12$$